# Is the order of adjectives acceptable: "slim yet athletic bronzed man", "ugly wide wounds", "deep dark blue waters"?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives, adjective-order

Is the order of adjectives correct in the following sentence?

Also, is the usage of "yet" correct?

> "He was a **slim yet athletic bronzed man**."

What about this one?

> "I gasped as I saw his legs torn with **ugly wide wounds** that bore
>   the signs of shark bites."

And this one:

> "A man on the deck, was shouting, flapping his hands and pointing to
>   the below, the **deep dark blue** waters."
>   "The invader was a ten foot shark."

Comment: They all look good to me. I'm not sure if there are technical rules to which should go first. I think it has to do more with how it sounds the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the three sentences in concern are just perfect.

Straight from the [British Council English Grammar page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives)

[image: Order of adjectives]

Check it and you'll find that you have put the order in a right way.

In most of your sentences, the order is 'general/specific opinion > size > color > material

Comment: According to this list; does 'deep' in 'deep dark blue' express the size?